# What is the difference between "lesen" and "sehen"?

Tags: semantics

I know that lesen mean read and sehen mean see.

i.e :
**Lese** ich recht?

**Sehe** ich recht?

What does two word mean in semantic features? Thank you.

Comment: Well... *lesen* is "to read", *sehen* is "to see".

Comment: Since not all German native speakers are familiar with linguistic terms, it might help to describe what you mean with "_mean in semantic features_". Could you maybe give an example?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach The OP seems to know this, according to their first sentence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that you are asking for the right way to express disbelief in what is in front of your eyes. "Sehe ich recht?" or "sehe ich (das) richtig?" would be the general term for that, including disbelief upon something written. "Lese ich recht" *could* be used only on written text and still would be the lesser frequently used form.

If that was not the point you were asking for, please update your question with more details.